# How did the 2020s congressional districts so far vote for president in 2020 relative to the nation?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, redistricting

FiveThirtyEight has a [redistricting](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/redistricting-2022-maps/) tracker. It found that there are "181 Democratic leaning seats and 177 Republican leaning seats".

My issue is twofold: the data isn't just based off of one election, and it doesn't directly say the tilt of the "highly competitive districts".

My question is how did all of the districts in states where the maps were signed into law (excluding Ohio because of legal issues involving the State Supreme Court) vote relative to the nation? In other words, excluding 3rd parties, how many seats were more pro Biden and more pro-Trump than the national popular vote?

Note: this question is to see which party has an edge so far in redistricting when looking at a singular election. Whoever answers is welcome to update it. And the answer for Ohio is currently 12R-3D based on Politico's redistricting tracker.

Comment: Related http://washparkprophet.blogspot.com/2022/03/the-2022-election-preview.html As of last count there were not finalized maps in FL, LA, MO, NH, and OH.

Answer (score 1):

The Daily Kos' 'Pres-by-CD' project is usually where I'd look for data of this sort, but it looks like they're quite far behind with [their calculations](https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2021/9/29/2055001/-Daily-Kos-Elections-2020-presidential-results-by-congressional-district-for-new-and-old-districts) this year - at the time of writing they've only run the numbers on 20 of the 435 districts. Nevertheless, eventually I'd imagine this will be the best source for this kind of data.

In the meantime, I've used Dave's Redistricting App to look at the [official plans for each state](https://davesredistricting.org/maps#list::Official-Maps) which have finished being litigated on (based on 538's article you linked), and come up with the results below. There are currently 16 states which still have their redistricting plans in litigation, and 4 states yet to approve a plan, but the remaining 30 states (24 of which have completed their plans, the remainder having at-large districts) are shown in the table below. Based on the 2020 national popular vote for President, 115 districts voted more for Biden relative to the nation, while 83 voted more for Trump.

| State | Biden | Trump | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | 1 | 6 | 7 |
| Alaska | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Arizona | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| Arkansas | - | - | 4 |
| California | 44 | 8 | 52 |
| Colorado | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| Connecticut | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| Delaware | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Florida | - | - | 28 |
| Georgia | - | - | 14 |
| Hawaii | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| Idaho | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| Illinois | 14 | 3 | 17 |
| Indiana | 2 | 7 | 9 |
| Iowa | 0 | 4 | 4 |
| Kansas | - | - | 4 |
| Kentucky | - | - | 6 |
| Louisiana | - | - | 6 |
| Maine | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Maryland | - | - | 8 |
| Massachusetts | 9 | 0 | 9 |
| Michigan | - | - | 13 |
| Minnesota | 4 | 4 | 8 |
| Mississippi | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| Missouri | - | - | 8 |
| Montana | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| Nebraska | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Nevada | - | - | 4 |
| New Hampshire | - | - | 2 |
| New Jersey | - | - | 12 |
| New Mexico | - | - | 3 |
| New York | - | - | 26 |
| North Carolina | - | - | 14 |
| North Dakota | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Ohio | - | - | 15 |
| Oklahoma | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| Oregon | 5 | 1 | 6 |
| Pennsylvania | - | - | 17 |
| Rhode Island | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| South Carolina | - | - | 7 |
| South Dakota | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Tennessee | 1 | 8 | 9 |
| Texas | - | - | 38 |
| Utah | 0 | 4 | 4 |
| Vermont | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Virginia | 6 | 5 | 11 |
| Washington | 7 | 3 | 10 |
| West Virginia | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| Wisconsin | - | - | 8 |
| Wyoming | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Total | 115 | 83 | 198/435 |